# iOS Container Views storyboard only?

Tags: ios, storyboard, uicontainerview

I am making a storyboard free app, and I would like to know if i can implement a container view system without using a storyboard. Thank you.

Comment: Yes but the container view system has a good automated memory management.

Comment: But you are right. I think i am going to go with that :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it programatically here is how you embed the view controller with Storyboards:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    _embeddedController = (EmbeddedViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"embeddedController"];


    [self addChildViewController:_openGLController];
    [self.view addSubview:_embeddedController.view];
    [self didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```